# Stepper motor based system design questions

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, motor-controller

The motors I am working with are [57BYGH56-401A](https://roboeq.ir/files/id/2664/name/57BYGH56-401A.pdf/).
I have 4 stepper motor controllers, they are: [M335](http://www.gbeshop.com/InfoBase/downloads/M335_User_Manual-EN.pdf).

Now the stepper motor is rated for 24 volt 2.8 ampere per phase.

I have a few simple questions.

The motor has 2 phase, so does that mean the power draw is 2.8*2=5.6 A?

The controller has peak 3.5 and continuous 3 ampere output. Does this mean the controller can't use the motor at full power?

Also, will this mean, the controller limits the motor or the motor forces the controller to function above its capacity? (24 V input)

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on the controller. A good one would limit the current and not fail. A bad one would be overloaded and fail if you load it to more than it's rated for. Do you have a link to the controller datasheet?

Comment: oh sorry it is m335 not m355. This is the link for its documentation. http://www.gbeshop.com/InfoBase/downloads/M335_User_Manual-EN.pdf

Comment: This is the link for the stepper motor documentation. https://roboeq.ir/files/id/2664/name/57BYGH56-401A.pdf/

Comment: if you already have the controllers, then they should be adequate. Given a choice, I'd go for higher current ones. The controller senses the current and will limit it. The controller is also modulating the current, so the input current required is not necessarily twice 2.8A, probably around 3A depending on what it is doing. According to the manual, it suggests a 4A or greater switched mode power supply.

Comment: I have a 15 amp 24v psu for the job. What does switched mode mean?

Comment: is this what you are referring to ? https://au.banggood.com/DM556-Digital-Stepper-Motor-Driver-2-Phase-5_6A-for-42-or-57-or-86-Stepper-Motor-Controller-256-Subdivision-DM556-Replaces-M542-or-or-TB6600-p-1838976.html?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_organic&gmcCountry=AU&utm_content=minha&utm_campaign=aceng-pmax-au-en-pc&currency=AUD&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_us&utm_campaign=aceng-pmax-au-all-50-220401-massa&utm_content=massa&ad_id=&gclid=CjwKCAjwtIaVBhBkEiwAsr7-c-uxjiu8AEw8DVGkH62NwsVgWXFJ6f0F0P2GCLqGZCzYFFHi4jAHhxoCIQgQAvD_BwE

Comment: 'switchedmode' is a design technique for power supplies. Most modern devices use this type of PSU as it is smaller, lighter and more efficient than older iron transformer based power supplies. As for motor controllers, there's plenty to choose from. I bought some controllers like you linked to recently. I was surprised at how quiet the motor was for such a cheap controller. The older ones I had were much noisier.